# SharePoint Document Library version restore not behaving as expected

Tags: sharepoint

I have some code which I am attempting to use to "rollback" a sharepoint document and it's metadata properties to a previous version using ootb version control and the SharePoint API.  Here is a sample of my code:

```
int versionCount = item.Versions.Count;
if (versionCount > 0)
{
 // this only restores properties
 item.Versions.Restore(1);
}
```

The expected result of calling restore using 1 (the newest version before the current version) would be to restore the file and metadata.  Instead, only the metadata is restored and the current file is copied to the new "restored" version.

The versions page clearly displays multiple versions and restoring through the UI restores the desired file.

Furthermore, I have attempted to use `item.File.Versions` only to find `item.File.Versions.Count` is 1.

Can anyone provide any insight?

Comment: Silly question, but how many versions of the document are shown in the version history page for that item? First see what SharePoint thinks is the number of versions this document has, if it's not what you're expecting then at least you know it's not your code which is wrong.

Comment: There are 3 versions in the version history page.  Furthermore, when I restore the desired version using the version history page, the correct file is restored.

Comment: Might be of some help http://blogs.msdn.com/karthick/archive/2006/03/28/563045.aspx

Comment: No help there either.  If I retrieve the file object directly from the web/folder object, the SPFile.Versions collection still only contains the current version.  The versions page clearly shows multiple versions.

Comment: So it appears that the versions page generates a version entry for ever combination of file and item versions.  When SPFile.Versions is 1, this indicates that the file has one version in addition to the current version.  SPListItem.Versions contains all versions of the file, including the current version (at index 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions page generates a version entry for each relevant combination of file and item versions. When `SPFile.Versions` is 1, this indicates that the file has one version in addition to the current version. `SPListItem.Versions` contains all versions of the file, including the current version (at index 0).

When `SPFile.Versions.Restore(iIndex)` is called, the file is restored along with the associated `SPListItem` version which applies to this file

Answer (score 0):

Your 'SPListItem' would have a File property, type [SPFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile_members.aspx). This also has a .Versions property.. you might have to use that or both.

Comment: In this case, item.File.Versions.Count is 1.